# Calculation of the Tetrad components for a linearly independent basis of coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I don't know whether MSE would be a good home for this question but it seemed that physicists are very well versed with these terms.

If we assume that the coordinates basis of a manifold (minkowskian) is linearly independent and hence take the basis of the coordinates $x^{\mu}$ to be equal to the linear combination of the tetrad $V^{\mu}_{\nu}$ where, these tetrads are just the consecutive derivatives of the spacetime coordinates $x^{\mu}$ wrt to the affine parameter and are hence orthogonlaised using the Gram-Schmidt process.

I got the 1st and the 2nd term to be:

$$V_{0}^{\mu} = \dot{x^{\mu}} \\ \\
V_{1}^{\mu} =\frac{\ddot{x^{\alpha}}}{\sqrt{(-\ddot{x_{\alpha}}\ddot{x^{\alpha}})}} \\ \\$$

I am unable to match my expression for the third component to the already existing expression in the form of:

$$V_{2}^{\mu} = \frac{(\ddot{x_{\gamma}} \ddot{x^{\gamma}})\dddot{x^{\mu}} - (\ddot{x_{\gamma}} \ddot{x^{\gamma}})\ddot{x^{\mu}} + (\ddot{x_{\gamma}} \ddot{x^{\gamma}})^2\dot{x^{\mu}}}{\sqrt{(\ddot{x_{\alpha}} \ddot{x^{\alpha}})^4 + (\ddot{x_{\gamma}} \ddot{x^{\gamma}})(\ddot{x_{\beta}} \ddot{x^{\beta}})^2 - (\ddot{x_{\alpha}} \ddot{x^{\alpha}})^2 (\dddot{x_{\beta}} \dddot{x^{\beta}})}} \\ \\$$

where, I'm getting the expression as:
$$V_2^{\mu} = \dddot x - \frac{\langle\dot x, \dddot x\rangle}{\langle\dot x, \dot x \rangle} \dot x - \frac{\langle\ddot x, \dddot x\rangle}{\langle\ddot x , \ddot x\rangle} \ddot x$$

Is there something important that I am missing here?

Comment: What do the dots over the $x$ mean?

Comment: Derivatives with respect to an affine parameter such as proper time.